# How does one verify a GPG/PGP key revocation?

Tags: public-key, key-exchange, pgp, verifiability

After revoking a key and sending the revocation to [MIT's keyserver](http://pgp.mit.edu), I noticed that the key is listed as such:

```
pub  2048R/XXXXXXXX 2011-01-01 *** KEY REVOKED *** [not verified]
```

Who is responsible for the 'verification of the revocation'? Does the owner of the key do this verification?  If so, how is this accomplished? Do other people *sign* the revocation and at a certain point it becomes verified?

Comment: I don't get this note either, but I do notice that *all* of the revoked keys I've seen on MIT's keyserver have this.

Comment: I believe e-sushi is correct, the keyserver accepted a packet that met the criteria of a key revocation certificate for that key, but does not perform a cryptographic check on that certificate. When you pull from your `gpg` client, it should do that check.

Answer (score 10):

> How does one verify a key revocation?

[As Jon Callas already stated:](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2985/12164) you simply don’t.

In case a different wording helps, here’s a quote related to the exact same question… https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2014-February/049100.html

> …
>
> > I revoked my key and on the public key server it says: "*** KEY REVOKED *** [not verified]" Why does it say that revocation is not verified?
>
> That probably refers to the point that the keyservers don't do crypto checks. It means: There is a packet which looks like a key revocation but it could be forged. If an OpenPGP application  downloads the key from the server then it does a signature check.
>
> …

Answer (score 8):

No, the user of the key does. A revocation issued by the key itself, or by a designated revoker, which is some different key.

If I am going to encrypt to you, I look at the key before I do, and I look to see if your key is revoked. Similarly, if I am verifying a signature your key made, I look to see if the key is revoked.

Comment: The key was revoked using the revocation cert and then sent to the keyserver.  I am unsure which step of the process I am leaving out.

Comment: So it's not possible to make the key disappear from the keyserver?  (i.e. "trigger" the verification on the server side, which IIUC should be followed by removal from the listing?)

Comment: @AloisMahdal "_make the key disappear from the keyserver_" --- keyservers don't delete data by design.